# Android java string division when has whitespaces (space)

Tags: java, android, string

i have an simple question. It is possible to make some function, that will division my string to several other strings? It will works like that:

> if string has whitespaces count spaces, make as many string as whitespaces count and division it by spaces? Like: "some string 123" string1 = "some", string2 = "string", string3 = "123"

Can someone helps me with it? Im a little bit new in this case :/

Comment: after java 6 (I think) String class has split() method. simple as that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 "some string 123".split(" ")
```